# How do I apply limit to this parent / child tree like table in query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `from_uid` (`from_uid`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `message_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `u
ser` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `message_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES `user
` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `message_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `message` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

This is a table to store user's messages and their replies. If I apply a limit to the whole query, let's say limit 30, the result would be 30 rows containing both parent and child messages(replies). But how do I get 30 parent messages with each message's replies?

Comment: If you apply a limit to *what* whole query? Show us your code.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli SELECT * from message where uid=1 limit 30; This query will get both parent messages and child messages(replies) in sum of 30. I'm trying to get 30 parent messages with each message's replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `message`.* 
FROM 
        `message` INNER JOIN
        (SELECT `id` FROM `message` WHERE `parent` IS NULL LIMIT 30) `ids` ON 
            `message`.`id` = `ids`.`id` OR `message`.`parent` = `ids`.`id`
```